# Store Single Variable from Input File into Array

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to create a logon program for users listed on a file. When I try to store the names into and array and check to see if they exist, I only return the header. So if I put NAME as the fname, it says it exists. But if I put Bob as fname, it says it doesn't. How do I store each first and last name into an array?

users.txt

```
NAME            PASSWORD        DEPT    AUTH
Bob Jones       12345678        MKTG    N
Sam Smith       password        MKTG    Y
Pat Johnson     87654321        SALES   N
Dina Shore      drowssap        OPS     Y
```

Script

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="users.txt" 

read -p "Please enter first and last name: " fname lname

read -a name < $FILE

for name in "${name[0]}" 

do 

    if [[ ${name[0]} = $fname ]]
    then
            echo "exist"
    else
            echo "Not Exist"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Why an array at all?

Comment: The assignment asks for it but I may not end up using one.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: the single `read` reads the first line's (the header's) words into the array elements. No other lines are considered. You might experiment with the `readarray` command, but that doesn't lean itself towards your problem. YMMV

No array needed. Use adequate text tools instead.  Try

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="users.txt" 
read -p "Please enter first and last name: " fname lname
if grep "$fname.*$lname" $FILE
  then echo "exist"
  else echo "Not Exist"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks! I needed to match the user name with the password in the file so I did `if grep "$fname.*$lname.*$psswd" $FILE` and it worked great.